# Why is the curl command for multiform not working

Tags: curl

I am trying to upload an image to a webserver api via curl but for an unknown reason it doesnt accept

I catched with my browser the following

```
curl 'http://hostname/api/v1/system/configuration/logos' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: *' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'token: xxx' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvd7cSVj7CC06O2Jy' \
  -H 'Origin: http://hostname' \
  -H 'Referer: http://hostname/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryvd7cSVj7CC06O2Jy\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="thecolor.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryvd7cSVj7CC06O2Jy--\r\n' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

When i try this with curl on my command line i do the following:

```
curl -i -v -H 'Authorization:Basic xxx' -H 'Referer: http:/hostname/' -H 'Origin: http://hostname' -F 'name=file' -F 'filename=@thecolor.png' -H 'Content-Type: image/png' http://hostname/api/v1/system/configuration/logos
```

everytime i do this the server responds with a 400 Bad request..

What do i not see?

The response from the server is:

```
* About to connect() to hostname port 80 (#0)
*   Trying hostname...
* Connected to hostname (hostname) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/v1/system/configuration/logos HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: hostname
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:Basic xxx
> Referer: http://hostname/
> Origin: http://hostname
> Content-Length: 8807
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: image/png; boundary=----------------------------1a898c51a0be
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2020 06:31:40 GMT
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2020 06:31:40 GMT
< Server: Apache
Server: Apache
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 39
Content-Length: 39
< Connection: close
Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

<
* Closing connection 0
[{"FullMsg": "Can't upload logo file"}]
```

Comment: **400 Bad Request**: The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error 

Have a look at `-H 'token: xxx' \`, I think you should add your token value here :)

Comment: the token i commented with xxx as it is a valid one :)